# Subpackage is not included in my npm module

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, typescript2.0, ldapjs

I have an npm module called 'ldap-pool'. This package depends on 'ldapjs' and also '@types/ldapjs', but for some reason when I install 'ldap-pool' into another project, the '@types/ldapjs' package is not being installed.
**The above is the problem.**

the package.json file for 'ldap-pool' is like so:

```
{
  "name": "ldap-pool",
  "version": "0.0.1011",
  "description": "LDAP client connection pool",
  "main": "index.js",
  "types": "index.d.ts",
  "typings": "index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "./@test.sh"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/ORESoftware/ldap-pool.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "ldap",
    "pool",
    "client",
    "connection",
    "ldapjs"
  ],
  "author": "Olegzandr VD",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/ORESoftware/ldap-pool/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/ORESoftware/ldap-pool#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "chalk": "^1.1.3",
    "ldapjs": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chalk": "^0.4.31",
    "@types/ldapjs": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.31"
  }
}
```

When I install ldap-pool in another project, I see:

[image]

if I hover over the red squiggly, I see:

[image]

**Does anyone know why the `ldapjs` typings are not being included when I run**

`npm install`

**?**

Comment: I don't think `.npmignore` or `.gitignore` should effect this, so I didn't mention them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typings files need to be moved to the dependencies section of the ldap-pool package.json.  Any devDependencies for a module will not be downloaded when the module is used as a dependency.

```
...
"dependencies": {
  "chalk": "^1.1.3",
  "ldapjs": "^1.0.1",
  "@types/chalk": "^0.4.31",
  "@types/ldapjs": "^1.0.0",
  "@types/node": "^7.0.31"
}
...
```

Comment: I swear it used to be the case that devDependencies were included, but maybe with newer NPM versions that is no longer the case, will test this. thanks.